# Connect bluestack emulated hybrid app to localhost

Tags: android, android-emulator, django-rest-framework, ionic2, bluestacks

I have created a hybrid mobile app using ionic 2. The app can connect to a Django-powered website on a localhost through Rest API when using "ionic serve" command (using web browser on my end device).

Now, I want to use the app using Bluestacks as emulator. The Django website and the API (running on the localhost) can be accessed through the browser app of the bluestacks. Here were the steps I performed to do this one:

1. Installed allow-control-allow-origin to enable cross origin information sharing on Google Chrome on my local device.
2. I have added ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.0.2.2'] in my django settings.
3. Access the django website through Bluestacks' browser using
       http://10.0.2.2:8000/

However, the mobile app emulated in Bluestacks could not access the API. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The django conf look's OK.

With this kind of problem, in general, i use tools like :

- [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) (free)
- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

to acces to my localhost from everywhere

example with lt :

```
$ lt -p 8000 -s andynionic
your url is: https://andynionic.localtunnel.me
```

You must also add andynionic.localtunnel.me to the Django  config

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.0.2.2', 'andynionic.localtunnel.me']
```

with hibrid, you probably do CORS request, see also [cors-django](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

hope it's help

Comment: Hi. I have followed the instructions but it is still not working. I think the bluestacks cannot connect to the dev server.

Comment: dont have more idea , sorry.